# Is there a way to specify date range when requesting a dashboard?

Tags: graphite

I'm using Graphite in a test environment where I run several tests of limited duration.  I've set up several dashboards that contain the general information I want to see, but it would be handy if I could specify the time range for a specific test in the HTTP request to show the dashboard.  I know this is supported for individual graphs, but is there any way to do this for an entire dashboard?

What I have in mind is using a dashboard URL that looks something like this:

http://graphite:8000/dashboard/adserver?from=18%3A06_20111201&until=18%3A39_20111202

Thanks!

-Travis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look at the graphite code, and it doesn't look like the dashboard view accepts `from` or `until` parameters for the dashboard itself.

However, looking further into `content/js/dashboard.js` file - it picks up the `defaultGraphParams` from a cookie. You can perhaps manipulate your cookie to set the values you'd like. I'm not entirely sure how easy solution this might be though.

Another option is to monkey-patch the javascript file and override the `defaultGraphParams` from the URL query itself (or maybe even submit this as an enhancement to the graphite project...)

Lastly, there are several good *3rd party* open-source graphite dashboards out there, some of them might do that. I believe [gdash](https://github.com/ripienaar/gdash) supports custom from/to fields. (shameless plug) My dashboard [giraffe](https://github.com/kenhub/giraffe) does not currently support it, but it could be an interesting feature request.

Answer (score 0):

(maybe a late answer to your question, but still, might be wroth)
If you are using render URI then you can specify a date range, at least according to the [doc](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.12/render_api.html)